# In redis cluster mode, Is the SHA value returned when we load the script is same?

Tags: redis, lua, jedis

I am using lua script to do 2 operations belonging to same key. Running Redis in cluster mode. Using java jedis library to connect to the Redis cluster.

The syntax for loading lua script is as below

```
jedisCluster.loadScript(<ScriptString>, <Key>);
```

It returns a SHA value which I can use in evalsha function on jedis cluster as below

```
jedisCluster.evalsha(<ShaValue>, <Key Count>, <key>)
```

I am handling NoScript error when executing above method and will load the script again.

Question: If I am loading the same script with different key values will the SHA value is different? If the two keys land up in different cluster then the SHA value is different?

I am trying to save this SHA value in string use it for all keys.

I know the SHA of a string will be same but I am not sure if redis adding any extra information to the script before generating the SHA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SHA1 sum of the script will always be the same for the same script (you can also compute it externally, e.g. using the `sha1sum` tool). This remains true in single-instance and cluster modes, regardless the number of keys and arguments that the script gets as input.